# How can I enable graphics on local macOS from remote Linux using SSH?

Tags: high-sierra, unix, ssh, graphics, x11

`host`: `Ubuntu 64-bit`

`local`: `macOS 10.13 64-bit`

I'm attempting to run a program on a remote Linux machine through `ssh`, and I want the GUI to appear on my local macOS laptop.

When I execute `ssh -v -X user@host` or `ssh -v -Y user@host`, I receive two messages that may be worth noting:

With `-X` flag:

```
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: Untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

With `-Y` flag:

```
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding
```

When I log onto the `host`, and execute `which xauth` I get the output: `/usr/bin/xauth`, which is confusing me because `ssh` is stating that there is no `xauth` program.

Additionally, when I do end up running the program thru `ssh` on my mac (just the command line version, no graphics), I get these errors:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

How can I fix this so that I can enable graphics to run on my local mac from the host Linux computer? Is this a mac problem?

Comment: Running X11 locally (on the mac) works, I assume?

Comment: @nohillside I can confirm that it works running locally